# Откровенный обман

Tags: фразеология

Является ли оксюмороном это словосочетание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это не оксюморон.
**Обман** может быть как скрытым (и именно таким он является в большинстве случаев), так и открытым (**откровенным**), когда обманщик не только не считает нужным скрывать свой обман, но и даже бравирует им (либо просто настолько верует в свою безнаказанность или наивность жертвы, что не считает нужным прилагать усилия для маскировки обмана).